# Can't connect to an AWS container service in Lightsail using it's private domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, docker-image, amazon-lightsail

I've created an Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) instance on AWS Lightsail on which I have installed nginx (1.18.0). I've also successfully published a docker image to an AWS Lightsail Container Service that, when the public endpoint is enabled, works fine. However, I don't want to expose this service to the public but instead route traffic to it through a reverse proxy on my Ubuntu instance.

My problem is when I try and curl the container service's private domain (<ServiceName>.service.local:<PortNumber>) from my Ubuntu instance I get `Could not resolve host servicename.service.local`. According to the [Lightsail docs](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-container-services-deployments) (section "Private domain") this should be accessible to my "Lightsail resources in the same AWS Region as your service".

I'm pretty new to networking so I would greatly appreciate some input. Is there anything else that needs to be configured in order to reach this service from my instance?

**Things I've verified:**

- The image is up and running and works fine when connecting to it using the public domain
- I'm running both instance and container service in the same region

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. I spun up two instances, one with Amazon Linux 2, one with Ubuntu 20.04. The AL2 instance can resolve and access a container service by domain name:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-176 ~]$ host nginx.service.local
nginx.service.local has address 172.26.17.185
[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-176 ~]$ curl http://nginx.service.local/
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

The Ubuntu instance cannot.

What did help was removing the `/etc/resolv.conf` on the Ubuntu instance, and replacing it with the one from the AL2 instance:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-176 ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search eu-central-1.compute.internal
options timeout:2 attempts:5
nameserver 172.26.0.2
```

It works, but doesn't feel like a particularly clean solution, since this overwrites Ubuntu's systemd-managed resolv.conf.

Comment: Great, it worked like a charm! This will definitely work for now. Cheers!