# AWS lightsail container service private domain - "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

How can I send https request from one deployment to another deployment using AWS lightsail's private domain?

I've created two AWS Lightsail Container deployments using two docker images. I'd like to send https request from one image deployment ("sender") to another image deployment ("receiver"). This works fine when the receiver's public endpoint is enabled. However, I don't want to expose this service to the public but instead route traffic using AWS Lightsail's private domain.

My problem is when I try and send https request from "sender" to the "receiver"'s private domain (.service.local:) I get `https://<service_name>.service.local:52020/tester/status net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` on the "sender"'s html page. According to the [Lightsail docs](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-container-services-deployments#creating-deployments-public-endpoint) (section "Private domain") this should be accessible to my "Lightsail resources in the same AWS Region as your service".

I've found a [similar Question & Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754995/cant-connect-to-an-aws-container-service-in-lightsail-using-its-private-domain) in stackoverflow. I tried this answer using my region but failed because Lightsail container required https while .service.local required http. After creating a Amazon Linux instance, I succeeded making http request but failed to make https request. (screenshot below). In the meantime, Lightsail strictly asks you to use https.

[image]

If I force to send http request from https webpage, chrome generates `Mixed content: The page at ... was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure ...` error. I can go around the https problem by using next.js api routes, but this doesn't feel secure because next.js api routes are publicly accessible.

[image]

Is there anything that I may be missing here?

**Things I've verified:**

- The image is up and running and works fine when connecting to it using the public domain
- I'm running both instance and container service in the same region

Thank you in advance.

**Some screenshots**

- Running dig inside docker's entrypoint script
  [image]
- Error message when sender sends http request to receiver
  [image]

Comment: The question got a down vote. Possibly this is either a trivial question or is considered a duplicate of some people.

Even if this is trivial or a duplicate to you, it will be very helpful if you could share some insight or refer a URL on how to solve this problem to this question.

I found one similar question in stackoverflow, but this doesn't answer my question. :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754995/cant-connect-to-an-aws-container-service-in-lightsail-using-its-private-domain

Comment: HTTP works? I don't think you would have HTTPS for private domains.

Comment: http works. 

However, because SSL/TLS is forced for lightsail web servers with custom domain, to send api request from frontend lightsail deployment to backend lightsail deployment, the request has to be an https request.

Comment: HTTPS is for public domians, and you write that you are using private names. In that case there is no need for HTTPS as entire traffic is internal, within AWS (no internet).

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. Looks like it's working. 

I used to get `Mixed content: The page at ... was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure ...` error from chrome. 

I could fix this by relaying the http request using local backend instead of requesting directly to the Lightsail deployment from html.

I will double check this again tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update. Problem is still there. I am getting "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http:/...' . This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." error from chrome. I am using next.js & flask and last night I could go around this error because I was using next.js's API routes. Today, I removed API routes because next.js API routes are publicly accessible (correct me if i'm wrong here), and it looks like I am back to square one.

Comment: Why you even use https if all traffic is private? For private domain you will not get proper ssl certificates to begin with to have valid https.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why ssl does not work for private domains as you would expect?

Comment: Https had to be used because the rendered webpage needs to send api requests in https as shared above. If you don't send request in https chrome outputs the above error: `Mixed content: The page at ... was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure ...`

I'll summarize what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my two AWS Lightsail Containers, Frontend Container with next.js and Backend Container with flask, talk to each other using the following steps:

1. Launch a Lightsail "instance" using "Amazon Linux" in the region I want to deploy my Container. Copy `/etc/resolv.conf` from this "Amazon Linux" instance. Update Dockerfile to overwrite `/etc/resolv.conf` file in my docker.
2. To make API request using http instead of https and go around the `Mixed content: The page at ... was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure ...` error, I used next.js' [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to relay the API request. So, for instance, a page on Frontend Container will make API request to /api on the same Container and the /api route will make http request to Backend Container.
3. API route was properly coded with security measures so that users cannot use API route to access random endpoint in Backend Container.

Answer (score 0):

https "pages" are often mixed content where resources such as pictures are drawn from the http folders not the "https" site folder, hence the request to get such a resource is http because of its configuration by location, so it will be called by http to obtain and then not be crypted (see server configuration for https folder location that requires access to it by that protocol).

Of protocols, the message from another post implies and may be that to communicate "privately" is NOT  a web service for public so such communications require using ssl:// secure protocol (alike using ssh://) NOT https:// secure public web server protocol of both require certificate. **(hazard a guess)**
ssl may be what is used privately across local.

The following AWS links recommend having differnet accounts for developing and the service.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-guide-to-locally-testing-containers-with-amazon-ecs-local-endpoints-and-docker-compose/
https://aws.amazon.com/cli/